# Custom Google Analytics API script is working, but running extremely slow

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am working on a project using the Google Analytics API for PHP.

Here is what I need to do: We have about 320 client websites that we track in our Google Analytics account. We are running into an issue where the Google Analytics code stops tracking (for various reasons) on some sites, and we would like to catch this issue before our clients catch it.

So, what I would like to accomplish is writing a script that checks all of our client sites within Google Analytics and calls the Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions for the last seven days. If there is no data over the last 7 days, the code is more than likely not tracking properly on the website.

I have created a new API project in Google and obtained a client email that I have added as a user with view permissions to each of my accounts within Google Analytics. I have a total of 63 accounts in my Google Analytics organized by state (New York Clients, Virginia Clients, Oregon Clients etc) and each of the accounts have multiple sub-accounts/profiles under each for a total of 320.

I have a script that is working, but it is taking a really long time to run. This script does work, as it gives me each profile in my Google Analytics that hasn’t had data over the last 7 days, but it takes about 65 seconds to run and sometimes I get a timeout error because of how long it is taking to run. I’m certain that this is because of the foreach loops that are making a TON of calls to the API. I feel like if I reduced the number of times I am calling the API, the script would run much faster. However, I’m not sure how I can code my script so that it makes fewer calls to the API.

Is there any way that I could speed up the script below by making fewer calls to the reporting API? Maybe I am going about this the wrong way and there is a more simple way to do what I want to accomplish?

**Here is my working code currently:**

```
 // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
 require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
 //initialize analytics
 $analytics = initializeAnalytics();
 //an array that I will be using below in the getProfileIds() function
 $ProfileIDWithDomain = array();
 //Calls a function to obtain all of the profile IDs to query against the Core reporting API
 $profiles = getProfileIds($analytics);
 //for each profile in the $ProfileIDWithDomain array query the reporting API to get data over 
 last 7 days:

 foreach ($profiles as $key => $value){
     //$key is profile id $value is domain
     $results = getResults($analytics, $key);
     //print the results
     printResults($results,$key,$value);
 }

 function initializeAnalytics()
 {
   // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

   // Use the developers console and download your service account
   // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
   // change the key file location if necessary.
   $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/{KEY_FILE}';

   // Create and configure a new client object.
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setApplicationName("GA Analytics Reporting");
   $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
   $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
   $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

   return $analytics;
 }

 function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
   // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
   // for the last seven days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:' . $profileId,
        '7daysAgo',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions');
 }

 function printResults($results, $profile,$domain) {
   // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
   // the profile name and total sessions.
   if (count($results->getRows()) < 1) {
     echo "<div class='item'>";
     print "No results found for $profile, domain name: $domain";
     echo "</div>";
   }
 }

 function getProfileIds($analytics) {

   // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
   $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

   if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
     //get all 63 accounts in GA
     $items = $accounts->getItems();
     //array to store accounts
     $AccountIds = array();
     foreach ($items as $item) {
         //for each of the 63 accounts, store the account ID in an array
         $AccountIds[] = $item->getId();
     }
     //now for each Account ID, we will obtain the properties
     foreach ($AccountIds as $id){

         // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
         $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($id);
         //if there are more than on item in the properties list (multuple profiles under it)
         if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $i = 0;
            if(count($items) > 1){
            foreach($items as $item){
                  //for each item in the property list, get the id
                  $currentPropertyID = $item->getId();
                  //list management profiles for the id
                  $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($id, $currentPropertyID);
             if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                  $user = $profiles->getItems();
                  // Store the ID with an associated URL/domain name
                  $ProfileIDWithDomain[$user[0]->getId()] = str_replace($removeChar, "", $items[$i]["websiteUrl"]);

                  } else {
                     throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
                  }
                  $i++;
              }
           }
           else{
              //only one item in the properties list
              $currentPropertyID = $items[0]->getId();
              //list management profiles for the id
              $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($id, $currentPropertyID);
              if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                 $user = $profiles->getItems();
                 // Store the ID with an associated URL/domain name
                 $ProfileIDWithDomain[$user[0]->getId()] = str_replace($removeChar, "", $items[0]["websiteUrl"]);

              } else {
                 throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
              }
           }

         } else {
           throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
         }
     }
   } else {
     throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
   }
   //return an associative array with ID => URL/Domain name for each profile
   return $ProfileIDWithDomain;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a lot of calls there.

List all accounts
List all web properies in each account
List all views in each web propertie.

You can get the same results back with one call to [account summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list)

Something like this.

```
$service->accountSummaries->ListAccountSummaries($optParams);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is EXACTLY what I needed :)

Comment: Its a great method isnt it.

Comment: So this method greatly improved the load time, but once I use account summaries to obtain the profile ID for each. It is still taking 2 minutes to run the script because for each profile ID, I have to call the API with $analytics->data_ga->get for each profile to obtain the 7 day data. Would there be a faster way to achieve that?

Comment: no there isnt. Things take time.  You can try batching if your making more thank one request for the same view. but you cant batch across views.  And baching is going to increase your changes of getting flooding errors.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on using account summaries.

You might also reduce the number of calls by using the newer [Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)

The [reports.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) method can take 5 requests at a time. However I don't know if it is any faster than the v3 method you are using now.

Comment: batching doesnt really help that much IMO.  You end up getting flooding issues. That and you can only send a batch request for the same view